# Ethernet controller EMC failure

Tags: pcb, ethernet, emc, layout

I designed my very first Fast Ethernet PCB and it is having a hard time passing Radiated Emissions.

The result came back from the test lab shows that it is radiating strongly at 125 MHz:

[image: RE result]

In the office, I have some near-field probes and a spectrum analyzer and I try to figure out the source of the emissions. When I place the probe around the bottom left corner of the W5500 IC (C11, C3, C6 area), I can see the below peaks. The rest of the PCB does not have any significant readings.

[image: probe with spectrum analyzer]

Below is the schematic and PCB design. The PCB has already been made, so I can't change the layout and routing. I have replaced jumper R28 with a ferrite bead and it has no effect. I follow [this reference design](https://docs.wiznet.io/Product/iEthernet/W5500/ref-schematic) from the chip manufacturer for this PCB.

[image: schematic]

[image: 3d view]

[image: TOP]

[image: mid1]

[image: mid2]

[image: bottom]

I would really appreciate it if someone could suggest what to do to suppress this radiation.

Comment: You can always wrap the PCB with metallic ESD tape if you can't change the PCB. However, whatever solution you choose, it might be more expensive than just redoing the PCB so you don't need any extra tricks to pass the EMC tests. So do you have metal case or plastic case around the PCB?

Comment: *the PCB has been made so I cannot change the layout and routing* Yes, you've made a prototype for EMC testing. These sometimes are good enough, sometimes not. PCBs are cheap. You can always make some more. Where does it radiate? Radiations come from external cables, so that's where you should be sniffing. Chips come into play once you know what cable and ideally what lines radiate the most.

Comment: The suspicious things in the layout is the absence of power planes - you're just using traces to route power around. Those may form parasitic resonators.

Comment: Is there a metal enclosure? If so, how is it mounted?  I notice the screw holes are PTH. What is SPI frequency? Does the level change with a ferrite bead on the SPI cable? Ethernet cable?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica On several occasions, I have seen users here suggesting signal-GND-GND-signal stackups, and on as many occasions, I've seen those suggestions go unopposed. A frequent reader of this site could easily gather the impression that this is a preferred stackup.

Comment: 125 MHz happens to be the Gigabit Ethernet symbol rate. Did the test lab measure with a network cable plugged in? If yes, what was at the other end, and also, what type and length of cable?

Comment: @Justme It is inside a metallic case. The case is grounded. We would like to get the product out the door as soon as possible, so maybe if some extra tricks could help pass the test, we can use them for the time being. After that I will re-design the PCB.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica can the radiation escape the case through the gaps? I will try sniffing the Ethernet cable and let you know the finding

Comment: @TimWilliams there is. The PCB sits on stand-offs. The part got grounded is part of the M12 Ethernet connector, labeled as GND on the schematic. The mounting hole on the top left corner is connected to this GND and through a metallic screw got grounded to the case.

Comment: @TimWilliams Right now I am using 35MHz. I also thought of lowering the frequency and see if it helps; I will try that tomorrow. I can try and add ferrite bead to the SPI cable; but not sure about adding to the Ethernet cable as I don't know where to add

Comment: @sinabala as I search, it looks like the W5500 chip operates at 125MHz. I instructed the lab to connect the cable while testing. The other end I assume to be a hub/switch. This is the cable: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01MPX2LV2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: What other connectors exit the enclosure?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have several RS-485 pairs working at 250kHz.

Comment: No power lines? So, internal battery power?

Comment: Yes sorry and power lines. 120Vdc which got stepped down to 5V with buck converters for internal ICs. One buck switches at around 34kHz, another at 330kHz.

Comment: @TimWilliams I changed the SPI frequency from 35MHz to 10MHz and the peak shifted. Now I have one at around 115MHz and one at around 140MHz around 45dB. Is this an indication that the SPI is the actual culprit and the Ethernet PCB isn't causing troubles?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the chip; is it possible to put it in a communication mode such that the Ethernet line is active while SPI is inactive or disabled? (I think Ethernet tends to idle with "keep-alive" traffic, so this may be trivial.) How are the other board(s) in the enclosure grounded (or bypassed or filtered) to the enclosure, if at all?

Comment: @TimWilliams Actually the Ethernet cable is left hanging down the table and not connected to anything. The cable we provided is not long enough to reach the Ethernet port at the lab. I did try to leave the SPI inactive (idle, no communication) and the 125MHz peak dropped to about 32dB. At the power input, I have two capacitors, one from positive voltage to ground, one from negative to ground. The rest of the circuit is floating and use reference V-

Comment: Probably worth linking this for posterity: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/665958/ethernet-external-magnetics-layout I would point to the unanswered comments, the concerns of which it seems have come to pass; as I've said many times, EMC is a holistic subject, and potentially anything in the system can contribute to a failure; total knowledge is key to reaching an answer.