# Ferrite on digital signal

Tags: emc, digital-filter, ferrite-bead

I have a SPI bus between two PCBs. From the master, the traces travel for about 3 inches on one PCB to the connector, 3 inches from the connector on the first PCB to the connector on the second PCB, and about 2 inches on the second PCB until it reaches the slave.

The frequency is at 35MHz and I have trouble with radiated emissions at 125MHz. I would like to place SMD ferrite chips to help suppress the radiation. I have used ferrite on power lines before, but never on digital signal lines.

Is there any special consideration while selecting a ferrite chip for digital signals? Where should I place the chip, close to the driver or the receiver?

I can also put an RC low pass to slow down the edges. In this case, what should be the proper cutoff frequency that helps with the radiation but not distorts the communication?

Comment: Can you alter the I/O drive strength (and thus reduce the edge rate) as a potential software-only solution?

Comment: @Attie I don't know if this is possible. I am using a PIC32MZ2048EFM100 IC. There is no drive strength selection that I can see. There are slew rate control registers, but I cannot find the registers for port D, which is the port I am using for this SPI.

Comment: See section 12.2 "_Registers for Slew Rate Control_", and the associated registers `SRCON0x` and `SRCON1x` ... though it seems to only be possible for some pins.

Comment: Should probably add this for context: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/699668/ethernet-controller-emc-failure the connector pinout, layout and cable will be relevant.

Comment: SPI clocks are usually not continuous. And 35 MHz does not result into harmonic at 125 MHz. I think the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> I can also put an RC low pass to slow down the edges. In this case,
> what should be the proper cutoff frequency that helps with the
> radiation but not distorts the communication?

Try a 10 or 22 Ohm series resistor first. If that doesn't work then add the ferrite. If you do get a ferrite make sure the impedance is high above 20Ω at 100MHz or so. Putting impedance on the line will slow down the entire circuit so putting it either place works if you just need a slower rise time.